# Create new folder with user-defined name and location in java

Tags: java, javafx, directory

I am using JavaFX to write a script, part of which involves the user selecting an existing project, or creating a new one.  In the latter case I have a popup window that prompts the user for a name and a place to save the project.  What I hope to do is create a folder in the place that the user specifies with the same name as the project, from here I will save different items to it and load them later.  However when I use filechooser to have the user pick the location for the folder it requires them to select an item before the chooser actually picks anything.  Then the folder that it makes has the name of this item in the beginning.  (For example if I picked the Chrome shortcut on my desktop the folder name would be chrome.exeProject1 or something like that)

I know part of the problem is because I reused part of my filechooser code for a different function where I required the user to have an item selected before they could submit it, anyway...

Is there any way for the user to select a folder, or just submit the filechooser without selecting any items and create the new folder here? (Inside the selected folder or in the current folder in the latter case).

relevant code below, any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
@FXML
private void submitName(ActionEvent event) {
    name = nameOfProject.getText();
    if (name != null && location != null)
    {
        new File(location + name).mkdir();
    }
}

@FXML
private void createProjectDirectory(ActionEvent event) {
    FileChooser projectDirectory = new FileChooser();
    projectDirectory.setTitle("Create Project Directory:");
    File refLocation = projectDirectory.showOpenDialog(null);
    if (refLocation != null) {
        locationOfProject.clear();
        location = refLocation.getPath();
        locationOfProject.appendText(location);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `DirectoryChooser` instead of `FileChooser` to let the user select a directory.

You can read the documentation on how to use these classes [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/file-chooser.htm) (it's from JavaFX 2, but I guess the interface is mostly the same).